# In Kotlin, is it possible to check at compile time that a specific value of a constructor is entered as a specified value?

Tags: kotlin

```
interface AnyClass

class ErrorClass : AnyClass
class ValidClass : AnyClass

interface Valid2Class : AnyClass

class Valid2ValidClass : Valid2Class

class B(
    @RequireCheck(valid = [ValidClass::class.java, Valid2Class::class.java])
    val subClass : AnyClass
)

fun serviceCode() {

    B(subClass = ValidClass()) // No error occurs
    B(subClass = Valid2ValidClass()) // No error occurs
    B(subClass = ErrorClass()) // A compile time error occurs because a class that does not inherit the type specified in annotation is passed as a parameter.
}
```

Ok, I know the simplest solution to this requirement is to create a common interface that only `ValidClass` and `Valid2Class` inherit.

However, this is a problem with scalability in the future, so I want to limit it to annotation as much as possible.

Is it possible for the above code to normally generate an error at compile time?

Comment: how about using [require](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/require.html) in the `init` of B?

Comment: @Statchu 
In the case of require, doesn't it raise a runtime error? I want a compile time error.

Comment: you are right, it causes runtime error

Comment: If you want compile-time type checking but you don't want to use built-in typing systems like interfaces or sealed classes, you might need to write an annotation processor. You could look into Kotlin Contracts too - those let you inform the compiler that a parameter is a certain type (``implies { myClass is ValidClass }``) and you should be able to chain different type checks with ``||``, but I'm not sure how much that would help - maybe a ``when`` block that covers all those types would trigger a complaint if you pass in something else.

Answer (score -2):

```
class B private constructor(
    val subClass: AnyClass
) {
    constructor(subClass: ValidClass) : this(subClass as AnyClass)
    constructor(subClass: Valid2Class) : this(subClass as AnyClass)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The method you wrote down is definitely the correct method, 

but if the number of parameters to be entered in addition to the parameter to be checked increases, or the type itself to be checked increases, the code will be too complicated.

Is there any other simpler way?